# Understanding Big O complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm having tough time in understanding Big O time complexity.

Formal definition of Big O :

> `f(n) = O(g(n))` means there are positive constants `c` and `k`, such that `0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n)` for all `n ≥ k`. The values of `c` and `k` must be fixed for the function `f` and must not depend on `n`.

And worst time complexity of insertion sort is `O(n^2)`.

I want to understand what is `f(n)`, `g(n)`, `c` and `k` here in case of insertion sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

It is not that easy to formalize an algorithm such that you can apply Big-O formally, it is a mathematical concept and does not easily translate to algorithms. Typically you would measure the amount of *"computation steps"* needed to perform the operation based on the size of the input.

- So `f` is the function that measures how many computation steps the algorithm performs.
- `n` is the size of the input, for example `5` for a list like `[4, 2, 9, 8, 2]`.
- `g` is the function you measure against, so `g = n^2` if you check for `O(n^2)`.
- `c` and `k` heavily depend on the specific algorithm and how exactly `f` looks like.

---

### Example

The biggest issue with formalizing an algorithm is that you can not really tell exactly how many computation steps are performed. Let's say we have the following Java code:

```
public static void printAllEven(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

How many steps does it perform? How deep should we go? What about `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`? Those are multiple statements which are executed during the loop. What about `i % 2`? Can we assume this is a *"single operation"*? On which level, one CPU cycle? One assembly line? What about the `println(i)`, how many computation steps does it need, 1 or 5 or maybe 200?

This is not practical. We do not know the exact amount, we have to abstract and say it is a constant `A`, `B` and `C` amount of steps, which is okay since it runs in constant time.

---

After simplifying the analysis, we can say that we are effectively only interested in how often `println(i)` is called.

This leads to the observation that we call it precisely `n / 2` times (since we have so many even numbers between `0` and `n`.

The *exact formula* for `f` using aboves constants would yield something like

```
n * A + n * B + n/2 * C
```

But since constants do not really play any role (they vanish in `c`), we could also just ignore this and simplify.

---

Now you are left with proving that `n / 2` is in `O(n^2)`, for example. By doing that, you will also get concrete numbers for `c` and `k`. Example:

```
n / 2 <= n <= 1 * n^2 // for all n >= 0
```

So by choosing `c = 1` and `k = 0` you have proven the claim. Other values for `c` and `k` work as well, example:

```
n / 2 <= 100 * n <= 5 * n^2 // for all n >= 20
```

Here we have choosen `c = 5` and `k = 20`.

---

You could play the same game with the full formula as well and get something like

```
n * A + n * B + n/2 * C
    <= n * (A + B + C)
    = D * n
    <= D * n^2 // for all n > 0
```

with `c = D` and `k = 0`.

As you see, it does not really play any role, the constants just vanish in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of insertion sort f(n) is the actual number of operations your processor will do to perform a sort. g(n)=n<sup>2</sup>. Minimal values for c and k will be implementation-defined, but they are not as important. The main idea this Big-O notation gives is that if you double the size of the array the time it takes for insertion sort to work will grow approximately by a factor of 4 (2<sup>2</sup>). (For insertion sort it can be smaller, but Big-O only gives upper bound)